# jquery keypress to add class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn jquery keypress to add class system.

I have tryed the following code but it doesn't worked. I have tryed with an ID here. When started the `#ttt1` then the the `#rb1` background color should change but nothing happened.

What i am doing wrong or what i need to do here? Anyone can tell me ?

This id **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/oxXyVG)** from codemep.io

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var ID = $(this).attr("id");
   $("#ttt" + ID).on('keypress', function() {
      if ($(this).val().length > 20) {
         $("#rb" + ID).addClass("ad");
      } else {
         $("#rb" + ID).removeClass("ad"); 
      }

   });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="tWrp">
      <textarea class="test" id="ttt1" placeholder="Write"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="br" id="rb1">Button</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="tWrp">
      <textarea class="test" id="ttt2" placeholder="Write"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="br" id="rb2">Button</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).attr("id")` the value for this is `''` in your code.

Comment: @guradio The ID value is #ttt1 the 1 is ID .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a variable `ID` inside a function which occurs on `$(document).ready()`. Inside that function the value `this` will point to the `document`. What you need to do is to define the variable inside the `keypress` event handler function.

Use class for selection and then use `$(this).attr("id")` inside the handler function. Also you can use `$(this).closest('div').next()` to get the next element in the parent.

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   //here  value for this is the document object and the id is not useful.
   $(".test").on('keyup', function() {
     //but here value for this is textarea where keypress event happened.
      var ID = this.id;
      if (this.value.length > 20) {
         $(this).closest('div').next().addClass("ad");
      } else {
         $(this).closest('div').next().removeClass("ad"); 
      }
   });
});
```

```css
.container {
   margin:0px auto;
   width:100%;
   max-width:500px;
   position:relative;
   margin-top:100px;
}

.test {
   outline:none;
   border:1px solid red;
   width:100%;
   min-height:100px;
}
.br {
   background-color:blue;
   width:100px;
   height:40px;
}
.ad {
   background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="tWrp">
      <textarea class="test" id="ttt1" placeholder="Write"></textarea></div>
   <div class="br" id="rb1">Button</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="tWrp">
      <textarea class="test" id="ttt2" placeholder="Write"></textarea></div>
   <div class="br" id="rb2">Button</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This might be confusing for a beginner, you say use `$(this).attr("id")` inside the function, then don't use it - I get it, but some might not

Comment: @rejith-r-krishnan Thanks for your answer. But it is not adding `.ad` from the `.br`

Comment: @DevStud Updated. Check now.

Comment: @DevStud Here we take the parent `div.tWrp` of the textarea and then take next item of that div. Then we get the `div.br`.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan I saw your demo and understood what you did on there for addClass but removeClass doesn't worked `$(this).closest('div').next().removeClass("ad"); `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105234/discussion-between-rejith-r-krishnan-and-devstud).

Comment: @DevStud there may be something wrong with codepen. The elements are being hidden. Try the snippet I just added along with the answer.