# Jquery change input class on typing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

As the title suggests, i've built a form using Bootstrap 4. The validation is being made in a PHP file via an AJAX call. Everything working fine except one detail. I need to change the input class from "invalid" to "valid" as soon the user starts typing something into the input field. How can I achieve this using Jquery?

Comment: Perhaps this would be of use... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767608/jquery-keypress-to-add-class

Comment: Used keyup event occurs when a keyboard key is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use add and remove class in jquery to change class attribute of input

```js
$("#check").keypress(function(e){
 $(this).removeClass('invalid')
 $(this).addClass('valid')

})
```

```css
.invalid
{
border:1px solid red;
}
.valid
{
border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="invalid" id="check">
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(document).on('keyup', '#myInput', function(){
       $myInput = $('#myInput'); //Object DOM Jquery, $.

       $myInput.removeClass('invalid');

       if($myInput.val().length == 0){
          $myInput.removeClass('valid'); 

          if(!$myInput.hasClass('invalid')){
             $myInput.addClass('invalid');
             console.log('invalid!');
          }
       }else{
          $myInput.removeClass('invalid'); 

          if(!$myInput.hasClass('valid')){
              $myInput.addClass('valid');
              console.log('this valid!');     
          } 
       }         
   })


 <style>
 .invalid
   {
     border:1px solid red;
   }
 .valid
   {
     border:1px solid green;
   }
 </style>
```

use 'document' as this will work at any time

Comment: please try to post a working snipet for better understanding.Great answer keep it up

Comment: This answer will give false positives.. To be sure the key pressed is not enter or escape, you have to check the length of the input field to be greater than 0.